# Не работает Ajax при отправке сообщения

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Здраствуйте! На локальном сервере (Денвер) все работает - сообщение отправляеться.
На хостинге - не работает.Иногда бывает правда работает. В чем причина понять не могу.
http://www.szsi.com.ua/page/page1/index.html
ссылка на сайт 
да такая ситуация : сначало использовалась библиотека JQuery 1.4.3 - все работало - теперь нет.
Пробовал другие библтотеки - иногда работает при библиотеке 1.8.3
Объясните  в чем может быть причина.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#form1').validate({
        // правила для проверки
        rules:{
            name1: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 30
            },
            email1: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            phone1: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                minlength: 5,
                maxlength: 15
            },
            msg1: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                maxlength: 2000
            }
        },

        // выводимые сообщения при нарушении соответствующих правил
        messages:{
            "name1":{
                required: "Заполните это поле",
                minlength: "От 2 до 30 символов",
                maxlength: "От 2 до 30 символов"
            },
            "email1":{
                required:"Заполните это поле",
                email:"Введите корректный email адрес"
            },
            "phone1":{
                required: "Заполните это поле",
                number: "Только цифры",
                minlength: "От 5 до 15 символов",
                maxlength: "От 5 до 15 символов"
            },
            "msg1":{
                required: "Заполните это поле",
                minlength: "От 5 до 2000 символов",
                maxlength: "От 5 до 2000 символов"
            }
        },

        // указаваем обработчик
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                target:'#preview1',
                success:function() {
                    $('#contact_form1').slideUp("fast", function() {
                        $(this).before("<div id='checkmark1'><img src='img/check.png'><p>Спасибо, Ваша заявка успешно принята :)</p></div>");
                    })
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуй добавить "async:false":

```
$(form).ajaxSubmit({
    target: '#preview1',
    async: false, 
    success: function() {
```

Comment: не работает

Comment: Нестабильная работа хостинга. Всем спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

В jQuery, начиная с версии 1.9, многое изменилось. Проверьте совместимость плагина (используете jquery.form.js?) с библиотекой. Или подключите последние версии обоих скриптов.

Comment: у меня версия 1.8.3 - это переходная версия
Вопрос в том почему на локалке работает и работала на хосте опр.время а сейчас на хосте не хочет работать

Comment: Можно продебажить, паредав response в success

success: function(response) { 
    console.log(response);
    $('#contact_form1').slideUp("fast", function(){
        $(this).before("<div id='checkmark1'><img src='img/check.png'><p>Спасибо, Ваша заявка успешно принята :)</p></div>");
})

Comment: не помогает - я думаю может проблема в хостинге - у них какие то глюки